# Bash script removes tabs

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script, which applies a python script to every file in a directory and saves the output to an output file.
The python script writes some tabs using \t and outputs this correctly.
However, bash does convert these tabs to spaces and then my output file is no longer a `tsv` file.

How can I get the bash script to write tabs as well?

$1 is the input directory and $2 the output file.
Here is the bash script:

```sh
for d in "$1"/*; do
    echo -e $(python3 script.py $d) >> "$2"
done
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quote the command substitution,

Comment: or do it all in python... mixing shell script and python here is overkill, sorry to say that. Python has the ability to scan directories and write files. Since you already have a python script, extend it's capabilities so it's able to do all the work (consider `glob.glob` package and use a loop). Plus not running a process per file will make the script 10 times faster at least.

Comment: no bash is well here, want to learn it and have to start simple

Comment: Jetchisel thanks that was the solution. Even if I still don't understand what the sense of these quotes is...

Comment: Why do you run the script using 'echo'? Just run it as python3 script.py $d >> "$2". It should do the trick.

Comment: Shoot, just make your python script take multiple filenames on the command line. `python3 script.py "$1"/* > "$2"`

Comment: @hafnerl : Word splitting is turning the tabs into spaces in your example. In the same way, a sequence of spaces would be replaced by a single space (try for instance `var='a    b'; echo -e $var`).

Comment: @hafnerl See ["When is double-quoting necessary?" on the Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748). Short summary: you should almost always double-quote variable and command substitutions, to prevent various weird effects.

Answer (score 1):

you must use double quote around your python output:

```
for d in "$1"/*; do
    echo -e "$(python3 script.py $d)" >> "$2"
done
```